# Date formats are displaying differently in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am exporting the reports data from DB to excel. I am having 2 DB(Local & QA) schemas and having same queries for reports. Here I am facing an issue with date formats. we are using **Oracle 12c**.

Date Format should be '**DD-MON-YY**' like '**01-AUG-18**'
While exporting data to excel,
from local db, it exporting date like '**12-09-18**'.
from QA db, it exporting date like '**12-AUG-18**'.
Query is :

```
select trim(to_date('01-01-1970 00','DD-MM-YYYY hh24') + (createdtime)/1000/60/60/24) 
  from TBL_RESPONSESUMMARY;
```

Can any one guide me please.

Comment: I wonder what the data type of `createdtime` column is ..?

Comment: Created time data type is Number and storing the date in milli secs format in  DB.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TO_CHAR` to explicitly specify the format model you want to use to output the date:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE '1970-01-01' + createdtime/1000/60/60/24, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
FROM   TBL_RESPONSESUMMARY;
```

What your query does is:

1. `to_date('01-01-1970 00','DD-MM-YYYY hh24')` generates your epoch value as a `DATE` data type;
2. `+ (createdtime)/1000/60/60/24` adds your milliseconds offset value to it (and the data type will remain as a `DATE`);
3. `trim( string_value )` takes a string value and removes leading and trailing white space; however, your input value is a `DATE` not a string so Oracle must perform an implicit cast using `TO_CHAR` and it uses the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter. On your local database this is probably `DD-MM-RR` but on the QA database it is `DD-MON-RR` so you get different values.

You could change the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` so that it is consistent on both databases - however, it is better to use an explicit call to `TO_CHAR` so you are not relying on session variables and implicit casts.

Answer (score 0):

You have different date format between two databases. Run this command on local database to change date format

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-Mon-YY';
```